# JMX ports added to startup script in weblogic server

Tags: jmx, weblogic-10.x

I have a weblogic cluster env with one admin and two managed servers, i need JMX ports added to startup script. 
I have two shell script to start admin and managed server.

Please advice how to add the JMX port in the start up script.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following JVM parameters to your Weblogic startup scripts

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888

Goto admin console> server> click on managed server > server start > Argument.

You can add above parameter in under argument list.

Answer (score 0):

also add    -`Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder` in the arguments list